# ASP.NET Core + ESP32 HTTP Requests, GET returns code 200, but content is not readable

Tags: arduino, esp32

I need to make a get request to my ASP.NET Core Server from ESP32 controller. Problem is, request succeeds, but I cannot read the string, cause it contains strange characters (image below)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "HTTPClient.h"

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "pass";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");  

}

void loop() {

  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { 

    HTTPClient http;   
    http.begin("http://172.16.1.146:45455/api/controller/getlastresult/1");

    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        

    if (httpCode == 200) {
        String payload = http.getString();    
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }     
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }

    http.end();
  }

  delay(1000);

}
```

I noticed that if I change the url, for example put https://httpbin.org/get there, it works fine

[image]

So, I guess problem is in my ASP.NET Core code. Here is the code of this request:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/controller/getlastresult/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetLatestResultForController(string id)
    {
        var list = _dbAccessLayer.GetAllVoteResults();
        var appropriateResults = list.Where(item => item.DeviceId.Equals(id) && item.Status == "Finished")
            .OrderBy(item => item.TimeStarted);

        if (appropriateResults.Any())
            return Ok(appropriateResults.Last().Result);

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

In postman this works fine, so I am very confused

[image]

Hope, you can help me out with this one, thanks

Comment: Since it works with Postman, I’m going to assume that this is not a server problem and I’m going to remove the ASP.NET Core tag from the question.

Comment: Can you check the response headers? It’s possible that the returned content type is in a way that the client does not support. For example, the result could be compressed or something.

Comment: @poke as I said, I tried another URL with client code and it works fine, so clearly it's something with server part

Comment: To figure this out properly, you could set up a proxy, e.g. using Fiddler, and record the HTTP requests on a raw level (also using Fiddler). That way, you can know for sure what the difference between successful (e.g. Postman) and failing requests is.

Comment: @poke ok, I looked in postman, I have text/plain for my url and application/json for the successful one. So what do I do to my request code to make response application/json?

Comment: “clearly it's something with server part” – Yet you also tried it with a different client and that worked. So you have both: A working server and a working client.

Comment: You can send HTTP headers using e.g. `http.sendHeader("Accept", "application/json");` I think it has to come after the `http.begin` call.

Comment: @poke I managed to make it application/json; charset="utf-8" by adding this line to asp net core code: Response.ContentType = "application/json;";
How do I set charset? I don't need utf-8, just plain ascii